Vim function for substitution of a regex
I want substitute some pitches in a lilypond file. I would like to change for example the line
c cis d2. disis4 d8 beses16 fes64 gis aes16

to
c' cis' d'2. disis'4 d'8 beses'16 fes'64 gis' aes'16

I can do this with
:s/\([a-g]\(is\|es\)\{0,2\}\)\(\('\|\,'\)*\)\(\s\|[0-9]\{1,2\}\|>\)/\1'\3\5/g

How could I integrate this substition in a vim function?

You want to find any ([a-g](?:[ie]s)) and add a '? Is that what you want? ([a-g](?:[ie]s)*) replace it with $1'?

Yes, I want to do this, exactly. But I do not want to add a ' only. It could also be a ,

Find this group ([a-g](?:[ie]s)*) and then replace it with \1'? Does it work?

Sorry, it does not work at the moment. I tried it with s/([a-g](?:[ie]s)*)/\1'/g
and I got E866: (NFA regexp) Misplaced ?
E476: Invalid command

Try ([a-g]([ie]s)*) and replace it with \1'? s/\([a-g]\([ie]s\)*\)/\1'/g

This works, but when there's e.g. \times 2/3 in the text it becomes \time's 2/3, which I don't want

Try s/\(\<[a-g]\([ie]s\)*\)/\1'/g? You need a word boundary on the left side: \b([a-g]([ie]s)*). This \< is the start of a word in vim. Can you use Perl?

It appears you wish to insert a single quote after every lowercase letter that is not followed by a lowercase letter. If so, and if the regex engine were PCRE, you could replace, with a single quote, every (zero-width) match of a regex comprised of a positive lookbehind followed by a negative lookahead: (?<=[[:lower:]])(?![[:lower:]]). Demo...

...@jecxjo's answer here provides a table that gives corresponding VIM and PCRE directives, including lookarounds ( atom@< <-> (?<=atom) and atom@! <-> (?!atom))...

...@PeterLewerin's answer here suggests that while VIM does not support characters classes it does appear to support POSIX character class expressions (why I used [:lower:] rather than [a-z] above). Notice that at Peter's link it appears that VIM supports \l for lowercase letters.

I tried it with s/(<[a-g]([ie]s)*)/\1'/g and it worked. Can I integrate this search and replace in a vim-script?

What is this about, exactly? Using an existing, correct substitution in the context of a function or fixing an existing but incorrect substitution?

First, let's try and make the regular expression a bit more readable simply by getting rid of the excessive backslash escapes.
We can use  very magic (see :help /magic) mode by prefixing \v and get
:s/\v([a-g](is|es){0,2})(('|,')*)(\s|[0-9]{1,2}|>)/\1'\3\5/g

That's still a long command but now it's almost 20 characters shorter.
Let's move on to the actual question ...
On functions
You ask for a function and that term has a meaning in Vim terminology, see :help user-functions.
The way to do it is actually pretty straightforward: just wrap your commands in the :function, :endfunction commands like this:
function MySubst() abort
    s/\v([a-g](is|es){0,2})(('|,')*)(\s|[0-9]{1,2}|>)/\1'\3\5/g
endfunction

Even without a special handling for ranges, it will run on every line in the range which is probably what you want.
Functions are powerful but a bit awkward to call and thus usually not used as user interface.
In fact, you will need the :call command as in :call MySubst().
There are two more user-friendly alternatives: user-defined commands and mappings.
It seems likely you'll be more interested in either of these.
On mappings
To create a new Normal mode command, you can create a key-mapping.
They are a very basic feature and covered in chapter 5 of the user manual :help usr_05.txt and in :help key-mapping.
The way to create mappings for F2 (pick any key or sequence of keys you like) is
nnoremap <F2> <Cmd>s/\v([a-g](is<Bar>es){0,2})(('<Bar>,')*)(\s<Bar>[0-9]{1,2}<Bar>>)/\1'\3\5/g<CR>
vnoremap <F2> <Cmd>'<,'>s/\v([a-g](is<Bar>es){0,2})(('<Bar>,')*)(\s<Bar>[0-9]{1,2}<Bar>>)/\1'\3\5/g<CR>

This creates mappings for both Normal and Visual modes that will run the :substitute on the current line or visual selection.
Vim does not understand that the | character is used in a regular expression so we have to escape it e.g. by using <Bar> as explained in :help map-bar.
On user-defined commands
You can create your own commands and call them from Vim's command line using the :command command.
command -range -bar MySubst <line1>,<line2>s/\v([a-g](is|es){0,2})(('|,')*)(\s|[0-9]{1,2}|>)/\1'\3\5/g

See :help :command for the details.
The -range parameter together with <line1>,<line2> will make the command run on a range of lines.
A call to :MySubst applies the :substitute to the current line. You can also prefix a range, e.g. :%MySubst for the whole buffer or :'<,'>MySubst from Visual mode.
If you really need to run the command all the time, you will want to go for a mapping.
Otherwise, I think a user-defined command offers a good balance when it comes to usability and precision.
